# Can I add methods to class by condition and call them?

Tags: python

**Here's my problem:**

- I have a class. And I have two objects of that class: ObjectOne and ObjectTwo
- I'd like my class to have certain methods for ObjectOne and different methods for ObjectTwo.
- I'd also like to choose those methods from a variety depending on some condition.
- and of course, I need to call the methods I have 'from the outside code'

**As I see the solution on my own (just logic, no code):**

I make a default class. And I make a list of functions defined somewhere.
IF 'some condition' is True I construct a child class that takes one of those functions and adds it into class as class method. Otherwise I add some default set of methods. Then I make ObjectOne of this child class.

**The question is:** can I do that at all? And how do I do that? And how do I call such a method once it is added? They all would surely be named differently...

I do not ask for a piece of working code here. If you could give me a hint on where to look or maybe a certain topic to learn, this would do just fine!

PS: *In case you wonder, the context is this: I am making a simple game prototype, and my objects represent two game units (characters) that fight each other automatically. Something like an auto-chess. Each unit may have unique abilities and therefore should act (make decisions on the battlefield) depending on the abilities it has. At first I tried to make a unified decision-making routine that would include all possible abilities at once (such as: if hasDoubleStrike else if... etc). But it turned out to be a very complex task, because there are tens of abilities overall, each unit may have any two, so the number of combinations is... vast. So, now I am trying to distribute this logic over separate units: each one would 'know' only of its own two abilities.*

Comment: It sounds like you're describing [class inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Comment: I know how to inherit a class, thank you. I have no idea how to add certain methods in the child class if condition is true and add other methods if it is not.

Comment: every child class has to have it's own methods. you don't need to add them by condition. Supose ClassA inherit from Class. and have additional methods proppers to ClassA.

Comment: This is not a good idea to be honest. These `abilities` which your objects are supposed to have, should not be methods, but maybe some objects that would be stored in some attribute of the class.

Comment: @UlisesBussi, that would require to make each child class manually. And then use some condition to construct an object of the right class when I need it, right? 
You see, currently, without additional methods, I use only 1 class and 2 objects to test all the variety of game units (~60), loading new set of data into class variables on each iteration... That's why I look for an easier, automated way. Isn;t it possible?

Comment: @ccre
objects stored as attributes?.. Could you give me a more exact hint? This sound as something I should look into, thank you!

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding, it seems that rainfollowerspb is describing that any game unit may have 2 of n abilities, where 10 < n < 100 (perhaps ?). If they use plain inheritance for each unit skill combination, this would require them to create 45 child classes at minimum, and close to 5000 at maximum. Since most of these child classes would just be reusing different combinations of 2 of the n abilities, I think rainfollowerspb is looking for a way to dynamically assign these abilities without explicitly listing all combinations out. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: First of all, you should read about The Factory Method design pattern. Secondly, an ability can be represented by a class. And you can have many subclasses of this class. Using a factory object you can create an object based on some conditions.

Comment: Methods should be methods precisely because they should be shared by every instance of a class. If they aren't, then don't use methods

Comment: @mirrorkeydev, absolutely correct!

Comment: @ccre, thank you very much, I will go read abut Factory Method and factory objects!

Comment: Your whole design is flawed — if there's that much difference between versions of the class you need define separate classes (perhaps with a single abstract base class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the best solution was the classical **factory method** and **factory class**. Like this:

```
import abc
import Actions     # a module that works as a library of standard actions


def make_creature(some_params):
    creature_factory = CreatureFactory()
    tempCreature = creature_factory.make_creature(some_params)
    return tempCreature


class CreatureFactory:
    def make_creature(some_params):
        ...
        if "foo" in some_params:
            return fooChildCreature()


class ParentCreature(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    someStaticParams = 'abc'

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def decisionMaking():
        pass


class fooChildCreature(ParentCreature):
    def decisionMaking():
        Actions.foo_action()
        Actions.bar_action()
        # some creature-specific decision making here that calls same static functions from 'Actions'


NewCreature = make_creature(some_params)
```

This  is not ideal, this still requires much manual work to define decision making for various kinds of creatures, but it is still WAY better than anything else. Thank you very much for this advice.

Answer (score 1):

I mean I believe this is what would generally be referred to as a bad idea, but... you could have an argument passed into the class's constructor and then define the behavior/existence of a function depending on that condition. Like So:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, condition):
        if condition:
            self.func = lambda : print('baz')
        else:
            self.func = lambda : print('bar')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = foo(True)
    obj2 = foo(False)

    obj1.func()
    obj2.func()
```

Outputs:

```
baz
bar
```

You'd likely be better off just having different classes or setting up some sort of class hierarchy.